# Show that ord$_{p}2 = 2^{n + 1}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime divisor of the Fermat number $F_{n} = 2^{2^{n}} + 1$.

Show that ord$_{p}2 = 2^{n + 1}$

The order of the element modulo some integer is the least positive integer such that it divides the "maximum" order.

Some attempt I made:

Assume that Fermat number is prime.  By Fermat Theorem, we have:

$2^{2^{2^{n}}} \equiv 1 \bmod (2^{2^{n}} + 1)$

I want to show that ord$_{p}2 = 2^{n + 1}$ i.e. $2^{2^{n + 1}} \equiv 1 \bmod (2^{2^{n}} + 1)$.  The question I have is: How do you know that $2^{n + 1}$ is a least positive integer such that we obtain 1 mod Fermat number?  Can this be done by Modular Arithmetic, or is there a theorem that I need to use?  Well, I found the orders of an element that divide the order $F_{n} - 1$, which are basically in the set $\{2^{k} | k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409752/prove-that-the-order-of-2-mod-p-is-2n1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are told that $p$ divides $2^{2^n}+1$. So $2^{2^n}+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. It follows that $2^{2^n}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

The square of $2^{2^n}$, which is $2^{2^{n+1}}$ (to square, a number, we double the exponents), is therefore congruent to $1$ modulo $p$.

Thus the order of $2$ divides $2^{n+1}$, so it is a power of $2$. Since $2^{2^n}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, the order of $2$ must be greater than $2^n$. Thus it is $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: How can you figure out that $2^{2^{n}} \equiv -1 \bmod p$?  I would assume that you use some corollary to prove this.

Comment: We use nothing! $p$ divides $2^{2^n}+1$, we are given that. So $2^{2^n}+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. This says $2^{2^n}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Oh.  Oops.  I didn't see this one.  Thanks!  It really helps!

Comment: Actually, I didn't see this part.  I rushed through the proof, and until I check out this response, I understand what you said.  Again, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Some of these things are easy in retrospect, but that does not mean they are *really* easy. The congruence notation is very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Let the order of $2 \mod p$ is $d$, then $2^d=1\mod p$. Since $2^{2^{n+1}}=1 \mod p$, $d|2^{n+1}$, let $d=2^r, r\le n+1$. If $r\le n$, you will get a contradiction to  $2^{2^{n}}=-1\mod p$.