# prove that the order of $2$ mod p is $2^{n+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove this:

Let $p$ be a prime factor of $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$, prove that order of $2$ mod p is $2^{n+1}$.

I know that $2^{2^{n+1}} \equiv 1 \mod p$. But it only means that $ord(2)_p$ its a power of $2$ and divides $2^{n+1}$.

how I can prove that there is no other power of 2, less than $2^{n+1}$?

Answer (score 1):

If $2^{2^d}= 1 \mod p$ and $d<n+1$, then $2^{2^{n+1}}+1=2^{2^d2^{n+1-d}}+1=1+1\mod p$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $p$ is odd.

Since $p$ divides $2^{2^n}+1$, we have $2^{2^n}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, so the order of $2$ cannot be a divisor of $2^n$.

As you pointed out, the order of $2$ divides $2^{n+1}$. By the above comment, the order does not divide $2^n$. So it must be $2^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Key idea: $ $ prime $\,P,\ \ \color{#c00}{a^{P^{\large N}}\!\! \not\equiv 1} \equiv a^{P^{\large N+1}}\!\Rightarrow\,{\rm ord}\ a =  P^{N+1},\:$ else $\ {\rm ord}\ a\mid P^N\!\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{a^{P^{\large N}}\! \equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\Leftarrow}$